# Write an equation in standard form for the line that is parallel to the graph of -8x= 5 - 4y and has y-intercept -0.5

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I hope somebody can help in my homework

Question:
Write an equation in standard form for the line that is parallel to the graph of $-8x= 5 - 4y $ and has y-intercept $-0.5$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Since it's parallel to the given line then its equation is

$$-8x=a-4y$$
and with $x=0$ we have $y=-0.5$ so $a=??$. Finally write the equation in the standard form.

Comment: So is it 4x - 2y = 1

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$